# Task Object - Get Picklist Values by RecordType?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, activity, ui-api

The UI API provides a nice getPicklistValuesByRecordType resource but it doesn't support the Task object.

I've looked everywhere, but I cannot find an alternative solution. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get around this for the Task object?

I have a flow that will be built for multiple groups, but will include one field from the Task object where I need to tailor the selections based on the values for the specific RecordTypes. A picklist choice set won't work because I cannot enforce RecordTypes their either.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the Tooling API works (/tooling/sobjects/RecordType/......), however doesn't give you any Custom Field Picklists back in the response. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your interest in accessing the `Task` object from UI API.

My name is Jonathan Au. I'm the PM for UI API. I'd like to let you know that this object is on our radar, but due to some complications related to the internal implementation of `Task`, enabling this object for UI API is not a straightforward process.

At this time, we do not have a timeframe for enablement, but we'll be sure to circle back once we have clarity.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - This functionality will be huge for us. In the meantime, I have to store values in a Custom Metadata Type and use those to populate my LWC selections. I'll have to instruct my admin team to add a new picklist value in two spots for now.

Comment: is support for Task any closer?

Comment: @Jonathan Au: Any updates on this. We do have same requirement and trying to figure out a way to get picklist value of a Task object.